# render form in page--node--add--contenttype.tpl.php

Tags: theming

In Drupal 6, there was a method to theme the edit form for nodes of a custom type:

```
 /**
* Implements hook_theme().
*/
function hook_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
   'node-type_node_form' => array(
   'variables' => array(
   'form' => NULL,
     ),
   'template' => 'node_type-node-form',
   ),
 );
}
```

Drupal 7 handles this method with the following template files: page--node--add--contenttype.tpl.php, or, page--node--edit--contenttype.tpl.php.

I didn't find any documentation about how I should render form items in these templates. `$form` is null.

Which variable should I use to render the edit form for my content type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this code in `page--node--add--yourcontenttype.tpl.php`

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

$form = node_add('your node type');

print drupal_render($form);
```

Refer [Change aspect of node add form (not only via css)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51999/change-aspect-of-node-add-form-not-only-via-css/52008)