# Change aspect of node add form (not only via css)

Tags: 7, forms

I need to recreate graphically the "node add form" (my client has passed me via PSD the final version of the ***node add's form design***). Is there a way to manipulate the node add form ***design*** that is not the usual change using CSS?

Comment: get the form array using `drupal_get_form` and render it in your custom module.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Are you saying that you need to change design of `node/add` forms ?

Comment: Stroker: yes I need to change the form's design.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think that I have found the solution:

Theming Node Forms in Drupal 7 --  http://drupal.org/node/1092122

M.

Comment: May you expand your answer? Answers that are merely a link are not considered answers, on Drupal Answers.